# Regex to match one of multiple strings

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

Need help with regex to match either of the following:

```
data.testID=abd.123,
data.newID=abc.123.123,
data.testcaseID=abc.1_2,
data.testid=abc.123,
data.TestCaseID=abc.1.2,
```

I have tried with

```py
m = re.search("data.[test.+|new]?[ID]?=(.+)?[,\}]")
```

Comment: []s in regex work as "one of the characters inside. If you want groups, you have to use normal parentheses - (). And if you want a literal dot, you have to escape it. So more like `r"data\.(test.+|new)(id|ID)=(.+)[,\}]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
m = re.search(r"data\.(?:test\w*|new)?(?:ID)?=([^,]+)", text, re.I)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/agEW2w/1/). *Details*:

- `data\.` - `data.` string (note the escaped `.`)
- `(?:test\w*|new)?` - an optional `test` + zero or more word chars or `new` strings
- `(?:ID)?` - an optional `ID` substring
- `=` - a `=` sign
- `([^,]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `,`.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/L483Cv):

```py
import re
texts = ['data.testID=abd.123,','data.newID=abc.123.123,','data.testcaseID=abc.1_2,','data.testid=abc.123,','data.TestCaseID=abc.1.2,']
rx = re.compile(r'data\.(?:test\w*|new)?(?:ID)?=([^,]+)', re.I)
for text in texts:
    m = rx.search(text)
    if m:
        print(text, '=>', m.group(1))
```

Output:

```
data.testID=abd.123, => abd.123
data.newID=abc.123.123, => abc.123.123
data.testcaseID=abc.1_2, => abc.1_2
data.testid=abc.123, => abc.123
data.TestCaseID=abc.1.2, => abc.1.2
```